# Curry functions - How to call 3 (or multiple) functions?

Tags: kotlin, currying

I am trying to curry a function in kotlin such that i can call it like this

```
myAdditionFunction(1)(2)(3)
```

this call would return 6 because *1+ 2 + 3 = 6*

i just need it to perform an addition over all the numbers. actually  i really want it to do a builder 
pattern in the future but still trying to see how curry functions work. Here is what i have so far:

```
fun myAdditionFunction(x: Int) {     { y: Int -> x + y }
```

this works for two parameters. *so myAdditionFunction(1)(2) will print 3.*

i want it to work for 3 or multiple : here is what i have tried for 3 paramters:

```
fun myAdditionFunction(x: Int) {
        var sum = 0
        return { y: Int ->
             sum = x + y
            sum }
        }
```

How do i carry the sum forward and how to make it take a third inner function ?? it wont compile.

but it will not compile

Comment: Maybe you want to build this yourself, great, but if not, there are existing libraries out there that do currying, and of which also would show you how it is done.  https://arrow-kt.io/ is one.  funKTionale is another: https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale/wiki/Currying.

Comment: This has also been blogged about pretty heavily with great examples.

Comment: Just trying to do it myself so I can make customer builder. Good library I'll check

Comment: Cool, I'd check out those two libraries, and google the topic because there are many examples of this out there to work from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what's going on in either of your examples, and neither compiled on my machine (Kotlin 1.3.10).

However, you can do lambda expressions, as they allow arbitrarily deep nesting. So for 2 variables, you could have

```
val myAdditionFunction = {x: Int -> {y: Int -> x + y}}
```

And for three variables, you can go a level deeper:

```
val myAdditionFunction = {x: Int -> {y: Int -> {z: Int -> x + y + z}}}
```

Just for reference, a lambda expression (aka anonymous function) is in the form:

```
val functionName = {argument1: type -> return_value}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think something can't be an Int and a function simultaneously. Maybe use an [extention function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) on Int class?

```
operator fun Int.invoke(x: Int) = this + x
val a = 1(2)(3)
```

Comment: plus 1 great idea :)

Answer (score 0):

With Lionel Briand's great idea to create an operator extension function `invoke` on `Int`, you just need another function `curry` as entry point

```
operator fun Int.invoke(x: Int) = this + x

fun curry(x: Int) = x
```

and you can do exactlty what you wanted:

```
curry(1)(2)(3)(4) // will return 10
```